# What is the error in this fake-proof of the complex number i?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

The error is from the 3rd step to the 4th step. But why is this an error? Can't $i$ be interchangeable with $\sqrt{-1}$?

$-1 = i\cdot i = \sqrt{-1}\cdot \sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = \sqrt{1} = 1$

Comment: The third equality.

Comment: And the second equality. Square root of $x$ is uniquely defined for positive real numbers. Not so for complex numbers.

Comment: @Eoin I'm not sure what you're getting at. When I read your statement it appears true to me.

Comment: @Eoin Wait, you're saying $-i^2 = -1$?? I thought $(-i)^2=-1$ but $-i^2 = 1$. Hmm...

Comment: @Klik That's what I meant. I didn't add the parantheses on the last one. My mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ is valid for *positive* real numbers, only.